# Accessing struct member variables passed into function

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a struct stat variable named s inside a struct I defined myself as follows:

```
struct myStruct {
  struct stat s;
};
```

and I want to find the difference between the st_mode between two myStruct objects, so my logic is to point to that struct and use a '.' for its member variable.

```
int func(const void *a, const void *b)
{ 
  return a->s.st_mode - b->s.st_mode;
}
```

However, there are issues with this implementation:

```
error: request for member 's' in something not a structure or union
warning: dereferencing 'void *' pointer [enabled by default]
```

What do I do to correct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameters to your function are of type `const void*` not of type `struct myStruct*`.

Do you know for sure that they are in fact pointers to `struct myStruct`s? If so you can do a cast:

```
return ((struct myStruct*)a)->s.st_mode - ((struct myStruct*)b)->s.st_mode
```

but it's safer to redefine your function to only accept pointers of the correct type thus:

```
int func(const struct myStruct* a, const struct myStruct* b)
```

and then keep the rest unchanged.

Comment: I have to implement it using const void *, and I just need to complete the function body. Yes, when this function is called, it takes in the address to myStruct objects. Thanks for the answer by the way, it works.

Comment: In which case you'll need to do the cast (my first example) Although that seems like a fairly contrived situation.

Comment: I agree. I will have to inquire the reasons for this implementation. Thanks anw.

Answer (score 0):

Your function should be declared as taking pointers to `struct myStruct`, otherwise the compiler has no way of inferring the types of `a` and `b`.

```
int func(const struct myStruct *a, const struct myStruct *b)
{ 
  return a->s.st_mode - b->s.st_mode;
}
```

Alternatively, you may use casting:

```
int func(const void *a, const void *b)
{ 
  return (const struct myStruct*)a->s.st_mode - (const struct myStruct*)b->s.st_mode;
}
```